# Trigger event with jquery when 3 characters are entered in the input field

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, triggers, character

I have a HTML input field, lets say

```
<input type="text" maxlength="50" size="50" name="subject" id="subject">
```

I need to trigger a function on every 3 charachters entered.

For example:

If user enters "aaa" - trigger an event, the he continues to enter "aaa bbb" - trigger event again, etc.

But spaces should not be counted.

I need this to post value of the field to external API - to do searching.

Has anybody done this before?

Please help.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

try something like this. Bind an event handler to `input` on page load

```
$(function(){

    $("#subject").change(function(){

         var val = $(this).val().trim();
         val = val.replace(/\s+/g, '');

         if(val.length % 3 == 0) { //for checking 3 characters
               //your logic here
         }

    });      
});
```

Comment: .trim() removes whitespace from both ends of the string. You need to remove spaces from inside the string as well.

Comment: also for <input> the change event is deferred until the element loses focus.

Comment: anyway, it is exactly what i needed. Thanks everybody.

Comment: Wy would you use modulus? length can only be a whole number?

Answer (score 12):

If you want to actually do this in real-time while the user is typing and not require them to remove focus from the input, you can use a `keyup` event and slightly modified logic to filter out spacebar presses.

```
$('#subject').on('keyup', function(e) {
    if (e.which !== 32) {
        var value = $(this).val();
        var noWhitespaceValue = value.replace(/\s+/g, '');
        var noWhitespaceCount = noWhitespaceValue.length;
        if (noWhitespaceCount % 3 === 0) {
            // Call API
        }
    }
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d8L9G/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `vals.length > 0` in the clause as well in order to work when `length = 0`:

```
//for checking 3 characters
if( vals.length > 0 && val.length % 3 == 0 )
```